# Can I make my spaghetti sauce with puree instead of sauce?

Tags: substitutions, tomatoes

I have been making the same spaghetti sauce for about 50 years now.  It calls for 2 small cans tomato sauce, 1 can tomato paste and 1 large can of whole peeled tomatoes.  For the first time in all these years I purchased tomato puree instead of tomato sauce.  How can I adjust my recipe to use the puree or should I just bite the bullet and purcahse the sauce.  I'm not sure what I'd ever use the puree for.

Answer (score 2):

I've been making sauce for even longer :-) and I think you'll be fine. If you, like me, always taste after all the ingredients are in, even before it has simmered, you'll know what you have to adjust. My proportions are generally one 28-ounce can pomodori pelati (Italian plum tomatoes), one 14.5-ounce can sauce or puree, and one 6-ounce can of tomato paste. If you find the puree thicker than the amount of canned sauce that you usually include, you can use slightly less or thin with a bit with water, but I don't think it will be necessary.